# Optimizing of loading QImage from file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to load image from file to `QImage` with `QImage(path)` command.

Currently, I am trying to optimize my code, because two lines of code take about 200 miliseconds per image, which is too much because loading of more than 50 pictures takes more than 10 seconds.

```
QImage tmp = QImage(path/to/file);
thumbnail_ = tmp.scaled(200,200,Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
```

Image from path have about 5MB with resolution 4000x3000. I can't directly scale `QImage` and save it to `thumbnail_` because I need to save some information about it later.

Does anyone know better solution how to optimize loading that image?

Comment: Why do you need to load all 50 images at once?

Comment: @vahancho Because I am showing them as photogalery (GridView delegate), but all I need to show is just that 200x200 image.

Comment: Why not read the images on a new thread and post the results back to the GUI thread using a queued signal/slot?

Comment: Well, but I hardly believe that you can show all 50 images at the same time. So you can load the first few and fetch the rest incrementally as soon as you scroll down, for example. This is good, especially, if you said, you cannot produce thumbnail images beforehand.

Comment: @vahancho Yes, I can and I am showing all 50 images (I can show about 80 images on one screen), so I can't fetch them later unfortunally

Comment: @Brykyz, even if you should show them all, show some of them, than make placeholders for the rest and fetch the full images one by one later with, as suggested, threads.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I can and I am showing all 50 images (I can show about 80 images on one screen), so I can't fetch them later unfortunally

Yes, you can show the images later. Your display should be a view and react to the data changes in the model. As the images are loaded asynchronously, the model will signal data changes, and the view will display the upcoming images automatically.

Comment: Yes, I already solved it with signals and `QThreads`, thank you